# Two tails in distribution plots

Tags: r-mosaic

I'm learning statistics and R using the mosaic package, amongst others. For a two tailed test it would be useful if I could see(and get the results) from distribution functions without having to multiply by 2.

Is there any way do to this in the current version of mosaic?

Eg. instead of `xpnorm(1.96, lower.tail = FALSE) * 2` I'd like to get the same result without multiplying by 2 and shade both tails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xpnorm() intentionally follows pnorm(), so each only handles one (type of) tail.  You can, however, specify multiple cut points (say c(-1.96, 1.96)) to get a picture with two tails shaded.  But you will still need to some additional arithmetic to get the sum of two tail probabilities.

```r
library(mosaic)
xpnorm(c(-1.96, 1.96))
#> 
#> If X ~ N(0, 1), then
#>  P(X <= -1.96) = P(Z <= -1.96) = 0.025   P(X <=  1.96) = P(Z <=  1.96) = 0.975
#>  P(X >  -1.96) = P(Z >  -1.96) = 0.975   P(X >   1.96) = P(Z >   1.96) = 0.025
#>
```

[image]

```r
#> [1] 0.0249979 0.9750021
```

Created on 2018-08-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Going in the other direction (if you know the probability and want to find critical values), we have introduced xcnorm() for finding end points bounding a specified central probability.  Here is an example:

```r
library(mosaic)

xcnorm(0.90)
#> 
#> If X ~ N(0, 1), then
#>  P(X <= -1.644854) = 0.05    P(X <=  1.644854) = 0.95
#>  P(X >  -1.644854) = 0.95    P(X >   1.644854) = 0.05
#>
```

[image]

```r
#> [1] -1.644854  1.644854
```

Created on 2018-08-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).